# Using Spring-Security PasswordEncoder with default authentication provider?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring 4.0.8 RELEASE and Spring-Security 3.2.5 RELEASE

I'm building a REST WebService using HTTP Digest to which only registered users have access to.

My web.xml is this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The applicationContext.xml contains my Controller/DAO important for this is only this:

```
<import resource="security-context.xml" />

<bean id="daoPersonal" class="com.test.dao.PersonalDAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Now the security-context.xml looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <debug />
    <http entry-point-ref="digestEntryPoint">
        <headers />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <custom-filter ref="digestFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="digestFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="daoPersonal" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="digestEntryPoint" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="digestEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="realmName" value="Contacts Realm via Digest Authentication" />
        <beans:property name="key" value="acegi" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="bcryptEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="daoPersonal">
             <password-encoder ref="bcryptEncoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
 </beans:beans>
```

and my PersonalDAO

```
 public class PersonalDAO extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport implements UserDetailsService  {

 /*my other code
  ...
 */

 @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(new Date() + " PersonalDAO loadUserByUsername: " + username);
         List<UserDetails> users = getJdbcTemplate().query(USER_QUERY, new String[] {username}, new RowMapper<UserDetails>() {
                public UserDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    String username = rs.getString(1);
                    String password = rs.getString(2);
                    boolean enabled = true;
                    Collection<GrantedAuthority> auths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                    auths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
                    return new User(username, password, enabled, true, true, true, auths);
                }
            });
         if(users.size()==0){
             throw new UsernameNotFoundException("");
         }
         System.out.println(new Date() + "Users Found: " + users.size());
         return users.get(0);
    }
 }
```

Without the password-encoder inside the authentication-provider it works as intended, using plaintext passwords from database. But with password-encoder (and password in the db changed to a bcrypt encoded one) the browser states the login was wrong and prompts again. From my output I can see that my PersonalDAO was called and found the user.

I still have another user in my db which still has a plaintext password, I tried to login with that one, while still having the bcryptencoder active I get this in my server log:

```
 org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder matches
 WARNING: Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

Now I can at least see that the BCryptEncoder is called, but it got a match, meaning nothing got encoded, and I still can't get in. (which might be expected).

What am I missing?

edit:

log output there isn't much but here goes:

```
Fri Dec 05 15:07:06 CET 2014 PersonalDAO loadUserByUsername: test
Fri Dec 05 15:07:06 CET 2014 Users Found: 1
```

encrypted password in db: 
    $2a$10$HWX95PBi7pob2bmIHXka3ecMcfsSvEifV3Z6J0CAb3vpWs8N9j5xS

Comment: Show us more log recording. I can see more System.out, please copy the output. And please copy here a password exactly as it is saved in database (just to ensure that it is encrypted in BCrypt accepted format, with seed in the beginning).

Comment: @MichalWilkowski added system.out and the password

Comment: Password looks fine (just like in my db :)), configuration also looks fine. Well, I give up. But you may do a basic check and call isPasswordValid with your password encoder to check what it returns (perhaps error is somewhere else).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The combination of HTTP Digest authentication and BCrypt password encoder is not possible. This is because the HTTP Digest algorithm requires that the password is stored in cleartext. You must either change authentication method or remove password encoding.

Comment: woah, Digest requires cleartext passwords? Ok, won't use digest then. Thanks!