# Spring Restful Web Services with Spring Security to perform authorization

Tags: android, web-services, spring-security, restful-authentication

I have been read a lot of literature about Spring Web Services and authentication methods, but I am still confused. This is my scenario and what I want to try to implement:

I'm developing some Spring (4.x) restful web services to consume from an Android application. That data are stored into a database, and I access to the database via Spring Data JPA. I have some models to represent the tables, so I'm using Jackson to convert Java objects into JSON objects that the web services return to the Android application. I also have some web services that accept JSON objects into the request to store information into database but I think that this operations aren't safe. I can't use SSL (https) into my server at least for now (I don't have enough privileges). Thus, I have to provide some security to my web services.

I'm thinking of sending a header with username-password hashed or encrypted into the request, but someone could sniff the network to get that information. Is this a good approach? What kind of encryption should I use?  How should I send the JSON from the Android application via web services (I mean plain text, hashed, etc.)?

How can I implement an authorization mechanism through Spring Security? I know how to use Spring Security with a web application using Spring MVC, but I don't know how to use it for a web service (although both are the same more or less). For example, I am not using a login-form into the http tag in the spring security xml. I'm trying to use a digest authentication and then I am using the intercept-url tag to set the path to allow access with the value isAuthenticated():

```
<http create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="digestEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
    <!-- The pages not marked are not allowed -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />

    <!-- Internal pages with restricted access -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/ws/**" access="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('ROLE_MY_ROLE')" />

    <http-basic />
    <custom-filter ref="digestFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
</http>
```

I have configured the digest mechanism as follows:

```
<beans:bean id="digestFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="digestEntryPoint" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="digestEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="realmName" value="Contacts Realm via Digest Authentication"/>
    <beans:property name="key" value="acegi" />
</beans:bean>
```

I want to use as a userDetailService my custom datasource to perform the authentication (I am using BCrytpt to hash the password into the database):

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select email as username, password, enabled from user where email=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select p.email, a.name as authority
                from user p, player_has_authorities pha, authorities a where p.email = pha.email and pha.name = a.name and p.email =?"
            role-prefix="ROLE" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="encoder" 
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
</beans:bean>
```

What property should I use into my digestFilter bean for that? Should I implement my own digest Entry Point?

Thank you very much in advance for your answers.

Comment: The combination of DigestAuthenticationFilter and BCryptPasswordEncoder is not possible, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317368/using-spring-security-passwordencoder-with-default-authentication-provider

Comment: Then maybe Digest authentication is not useful with rest web services... So perhaps I should implement a basic authentication and encrypt the password... Thanks for your answer