# Digest authentication with Spring Security, BCrypt and Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have implemented a Digest authentication in spring security it was working fine until I set it to encrypt with BCrypt.

```
    @Bean
    public DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint digestEntryPoint() {
        DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint digestAuthenticationEntryPoint = new DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        digestAuthenticationEntryPoint.setKey("myKey");
        digestAuthenticationEntryPoint.setRealmName("Digest Realm");
        return digestAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public DigestAuthenticationFilter digestAuthenticationFilter(
            DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint digestAuthenticationEntryPoint) {
        DigestAuthenticationFilter digestAuthenticationFilter = new DigestAuthenticationFilter();
        digestAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationEntryPoint(digestEntryPoint());
//      digestAuthenticationFilter.setPasswordAlreadyEncoded(true);
        digestAuthenticationFilter.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean());
        return digestAuthenticationFilter;
    }
```

These are the beans I set to enable digest and using them with:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(digestEntryPoint())
        .and()
        .addFilter(digestAuthenticationFilter(digestEntryPoint()))
        //.httpBasic()
        //.and()
        .antMatcher("/**")
        .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
            .deleteCookies("remove")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .permitAll();
    }
```

The problem is that the server side generated MD5 response and my own response do not match.
In DigestAuthenticationFilter.java

```
if (!serverDigestMd5.equals(digestAuth.getResponse())) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Expected response: '" + serverDigestMd5
                        + "' but received: '" + digestAuth.getResponse()
                        + "'; is AuthenticationDao returning clear text passwords?");
            }

            fail(request,
                    response,
                    new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                            "DigestAuthenticationFilter.incorrectResponse",
                            "Incorrect response")));
            return;
        }
```

The server "serverDigestMd5" uses the hashed password to create the md5digest, but on the client side(using postman) I use the unsalted password and thats how the response is generated. If I use the salted password on the client side it works, but that is not very optional. 
Is there a way to make it work without using the salted password on the client side?

Comment: If I recall correctly Http Digest authentication is always MD5 based. So not sure how you are going to switch that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Spring-Security PasswordEncoder with default authentication provider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317368/using-spring-security-passwordencoder-with-default-authentication-provider)

Answer (score 3):

BCrypt doesn't work with Digest authentication, in fact, Digest authentication must access the password in plain text (so you have to save it in plain text or encode it with a reversible algorithm (like Base64, MD5 etc), BCrypt cannot be reversed as it is more secure. Spring Security documentation states:

> It is possible to encode the password in the format HEX( MD5(username:realm:password) ) provided the DigestAuthenticationFilter.passwordAlreadyEncoded is set to true. However, other password encodings will not work with digest authentication.